# Shorewall / iptables accounting between specific nets?

Tags: iptables, traffic, reporting, accounting, shorewall

I have two servers on two different IPs, lets say they are: 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8. In addition, they both run some virtual machines, who all have private IPs 10.0.0.*. Now, these two servers only have a single ethernet interface each. I want to track total internet traffic to/from these machines from the outside world, but I do NOT want to count any traffic between the two machines or between the virtual machines. How would I set up an accounting rule, using either shorewall's accounting configuration, or plain iptables rules, to track this?

Currently, I have no way of knowing how much internet bandwidth I'm using, since when I look at the overall stats, it includes traffic between my two servers.

Ideally of course would be to ask the router, but that's not available right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
TRACK_INBOUND="TRACKING_IN"
TRACK_OUTBOUND="TRACKING_OUT"
#Space separated lists of hosts(1.2.3.4),networks(1.2.3.x/y) to separate
TRACKING_IGNORE="1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8"

iptables -N $TRACK_INBOUND
iptables -F $TRACK_INBOUND
iptables -I INPUT -j $TRACK_INBOUND
for ignore in $TRACKING_IGNORE; do
    iptables -A $TRACK_INBOUND -s $ignore -j RETURN
done
iptables -A $TRACK_INBOUND  -j RETURN

iptables -N $TRACK_OUTBOUND
iptables -F $TRACK_OUTBOUND
iptables -I OUTPUT -j $TRACK_OUTBOUND
for ignore in $TRACKING_IGNORE; do
    iptables -A $TRACK_OUTBOUND -d $ignore -j RETURN
done
iptables -A $TRACK_OUTBOUND -j RETURN
```

---

```
BYTES_IN=$(iptables -L $TRACK_INBOUND -nxv | tail -n 1 | awk '{print$2}')
BYTES_OUT=$(iptables -L $TRACK_OUTBOUND -nxv | tail -n 1 | awk '{print$2}')
```

---

```
iptables -L $TRACK_INBOUND -nv

Chain TRACKING_IN (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       1.2.3.4              0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       5.6.7.8              0.0.0.0/0
 123K   15M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

---

```
iptables -L $TRACK_OUTBOUND -nv

Chain TRACKING_OUT (4 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            1.2.3.4
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            5.6.7.8
 1116  679K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: TRACKING_OUT in `iptables -I OUTPUT -j TRACKING_OUT` should be better replaced with $TRACK_OUTBOUND, @Eddy